# Не отрабатывает дешифрование пароля

Tags: php, openssl

В процессе изучения ооп в PHP. Решил реализовать класс который шифрует и дешифрует пароли. Версия PHP 7.1
В процессе дешифровки столкнулся с тем что иногда функция дешифровки выдавала false и ошибку "Setting of data length failed" также иногда был возврат false при этом варнинге: "The authenticated tag cannot be provided for cipher that doesn not support AEAD". Вот код метода который выбирает произвольный метод шифрования

```
 protected function selectRandMethod()
{
    $arrK = random_int(1, 181);
    $arr = openssl_get_cipher_methods();
    $key = $arr[$arrK];
    return $key;
}
```

Вот код метода который шифрует пароль

```
protected function crypted($p)
{
    $met = $this->selectRandMethod();
    $key = $this->selectRandKey();
    //$met = 'CAMELLIA-192-CFB';
    if (in_array($met, openssl_get_cipher_methods())) {
        $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($met);
        $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
        $cryptPassw = openssl_encrypt($p, $met, $key, $options = 0, $iv, $tag);
        $return = array(
            'p' => $cryptPassw,
            'm' => $met,
            'k' => $key,
            'o' => $options,
            'i' => $iv,
            't' => $tag
        );
        return $return;
    }
}
```

Вот код метода дешифровки пароля

```
public function decrypt($p)
{
    $crypted = $this->crypted($p);
    $pass = $crypted['p'];
    $m = $crypted['m'];
    $k = $crypted['k'];
    $o = $crypted['o'];
    $i = $crypted['i'];
    $t = $crypted['t'];
    $decryptPassw = openssl_decrypt($pass, $m, $k, $o, $i, $t);
    return $decryptPassw;
}
```

}
Фишка в том что если в методе `crypted($p);` я укажу явно метод шифрования `$met = 'CAMELLIA-192-CFB';`, метод может быть любой, неважно - то все работает. Пересмотрел метод произвольного выбора метода шифрования - он работает, ошибок я не вижу. У меня такое ощущение что когда я вызываю метод дешифровки - он где-то теряет метод шифрования, но почему и так ли это - понять не могу.

Весь код и примеры написал сам по образцу взятому с php.net

Comment: Сделал небольшой тест, который выводит в случае проблем метод на котором была встречена проблема. Он показал, что не все методы одинаково полезны. Например попробуйте жестко установить `id-aes128-GCM` ему что то не нравиться, возможно длина ключа или еще что нибудь в этом роде.

Comment: P.S. А вообще не ясно, зачем бы понадобилось расшифровывать пароли. Пароли обычно шифруют (скорее хешируют) односторонними алгоритмами, не позволяющими его расшифровать. Для проверки пароля принятый пароль опять же шифруют и сверяют между собой шифротексты

Comment: @Mike я тоже вычислил эту проблему с методом шифрования - но не могу найти ее решение, кроме как явно указывать метод, что как по мне не секьюрно ни разу.

Comment: Насчет того почему дешифрую - хочу написать для себя сервис хранения паролей, там к учеткам разным, фтп, и прочее. Если я его обратимо зашифрую - как я его потом посмотрю если забуду?)) Или мне их хранить в БД в открытом виде?) Для авторизации и прочего - есстесна только необратимое шифрование.